# How to add trigger event at end of this line of code at bottom

Tags: php, jquery

At the top of my page, I have an option and answer control where the user is able to select an option from a grid and the relevant answer buttons appear depending on the option selected.

Below is the html code which stores the option and answer control features:

Option and Answer control on top of page:

```
<table id="optionAndAnswer" class="optionAndAnswer">
<tr class="option">
<td>1. Option Type:</td>
<td>
<div class="box">
    <input type="text" name="gridValues" class="gridTxt maxRow" id="mainGridTxt" readonly="readonly" />
    <span href="#" class="showGrid" id="showGridId">[Open Grid]</span>
</div>

<?php
    $num = range("3","26");
?>

<table class="optionTypeTbl">
<tr>

    <?php
    $i = 1;
    foreach($num as $key => $val){
        if($i%7 == 1) echo"<tr><td>";
        echo"<input type=\"button\" value=\"$val\" id=\"btn".$val."\" name=\"btn".$val."Name\" class=\"gridBtns gridBtnsOff\">";        
        if($i%7 == 0) echo"</td></tr>";
        $i++;
    }
    ?>

        </tr> 
        </table>

        </td>
</tr>
<tr class="answer">
<td>3. Answer</td>
<td>

<?php
    $a = range("A","Z");
?>

<table id="answerSection">
    <tr>

<?php
    $i = 1;
    foreach($a as $key => $val){
        if($i%7 == 1) echo"<tr><td>";
        echo"<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"btnclick(this);\" value=\"$val\" id=\"answer".$val."\" name=\"answer".$val."Name\" class=\"answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff\">";      
        if($i%7 == 0) echo"</td></tr>";
        $i++;
    }
?>
    </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The line of code which displays the correct number of answer buttons after the add button was clicked on is this code:

```
$('#btn'+gridValues).trigger('click');
```

Now I havn't included this piece of code but the user is able to click on the "Add" button to add an option type into the option type textbox. When an option type is inserted into the textbox, it automatically selects the option button the which the option value matches in the grid, because of this, the trigger code above is able to display the correct number of answer buttons by seeing which option type is selected from the grid.

The problem I have is that this only works for the option and answer control on the top of the page only. The user is able to add rows in the application and in each row, it adds it's own option and answer control. The code for appending and answer and option control within a row is below:

```
  function insertQuestion(form) {    



        var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
        var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'>");
        var $options = $("<div class='option'>Option Type:<br/></div>");
        var $answer = $("<div class='answer'>Answer:<br/></div>");

        $('.gridTxt', context).each( function() {

        var $this = $(this);
        var $optionsText = $("<input type='text' class='gridTxtRow maxRow' readonly='readonly' />")
        .attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
        .attr('value',$this.val())
        .appendTo( $options )
        .after("<span href='#' class='showGrid'>[Open Grid]</span>");

        $questionType = $this.val();

        });


    var $this, i=0, $row, $cell;
    $('#optionAndAnswer .answers').each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        if(i%7 == 0) {
            $row = $("<tr/>").appendTo($answer);
            $cell = $("<td/>").appendTo($row);
        }
        var $newBtn = $("<input class='answerBtnsRow answers' type='button' style='display:%s;' onclick='btnclick(this);' />".replace('%s',$this.is(':visible')?'inline-block':'none')).attr('name', $this.attr('name')).attr('value', $this.val()).attr('class', $this.attr('class'));


        $newBtn.appendTo($cell);

        i++;
    });


        $td.append($options);
        $td.append($answer);
        $tbody.append($tr); 

    }
```

So my question is that if this trigger: `$('#btn'+gridValues).trigger('click');` works for only the main option and answer control on the top, how can I include this trigger to be able to display the correct number of answer buttons in an answer and option control within a particular row?

I have the starting code to be able to find the row, just need help on how to include the trigger at the end of this code as there is no `#btn` in the option and answer controls in the rows:

```
$(plusbutton_clicked).closest('tr').....;
```

Comment: can you put it into jsfiddle so we can test the code

Comment: @marabutt it has php code in it so it won't work in fiddle, do you want me to create a quick example on a page and send you a url to it?

Comment: yeah just dump the rendered html

Answer (score 0):

So, you'll need to modify this to work, but would something like this work?

```
$(plusbutton_clicked).closest('tr').find(".answerBtnsRow").click();
```

Comment: I have tested your line of code but it hasn't worked. Within the row where it contains the option and answer control, if I previously had option type of "4" which means 4 answer buttons (A,B,C,D) appear, and then if I then select a different option type such as "7" as click the "Add" button, the option type textbox changes from "4" to "7" but it still displays 4 answer buttons, not 7 answer buttons (A,B,C,D,E,F,G).